# Am I missing something with `raw_id_fields` in my Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I am using `raw_id_fields` on a few foreign keys in my admin interface. When this is rendered, the magnifying-glass icon appears, but takes me to the admin list page for that model entitled "Select MODEL to change". I can then click on an item to edit it. I don't want edit the item, I want to select it and put the id in the form.

Is it possible for this to allow me to click on an item and select it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supposed to happen. The page after clicking the magnifying glass should be a *popup* titled: "Select {modelname}".

Are you not getting a popup? I can reproduce that problem if I go directly to the page in the URL, but it should be triggering some JavaScript to produce a popup.

I'd check for any JavaScript warning errors / make sure admin media is being served correctly, specifically this file: `RelatedObjectLookups.js` (do you see it in the source?)

Comment: Ah yes! I had some extra javascript in the admin template header that was conflicting. Now fixed, thanks!